Teradata FastExport Issue: Incorrect Export Column into Mainframe PS File
I’m trying to export data from a Teradata table into a Mainframe PS file using FastExport, but one of the columns contains a [C] value, and it’s not being exported correctly. Instead of square brackets I am getting a junk kind of data.
Teradata col contains the data like this: test [C] (12345)
After running the JCL I am getting the data like this : test ÝC" (12345)
What I've Tried:
I assumed this was a character encoding issue, so I added SET SESSION CHARSET 'ASCII'; in the FastExport script.I also tried explicitly declaring FORMAT TEXT and setting the output to MODE RECORD. I tried to declare the .CHARSET before/after the EXPORT statement too.
My code:
.LOGTABLE TERADB.MY_LOG;

DATABASE TERADB;

/* Set character set explicitly */
/*.SET SESSION CHARSET 'ASCII'; */
.SET SESSION CHARSET 'ASCII';

/* Export data */
.BEGIN EXPORT;
.EXPORT OUTFILE FASTOUT 
    MODE RECORD 
    FORMAT TEXT;

SELECT 
    COL_1,
    COL_123 (FORMAT'X(250)') (CHAR(250))  /* Column contains [C] */
FROM TERADB.MyTable;

.END EXPORT;
.LOGOFF;

Even after setting the session charset to ASCII, the [C] value is still not being exported correctly, and I continue getting junk characters in the PS file.
Is there a specific charset or format option I should use to preserve these characters during FastExport?
Any help would be appreciated!

The default "Teradata EBCDIC" character set is a nonstandard code page that maps certain special characters to different code points than the code page you are likely using for your "green screen" connection. You may need your DBA to enable one of the alternate EBCDIC client character sets, which would require a database restart. Or you could use a UNICODE character set (UTF8 or UTF16) to export and run some sort of translation after.
